# File directory token - image field - node author

Tags: 7, files, tokens

How to setup file directory where the images are saved to use tokens based on node author ?
I have all setup with current user, but this is not good if moderator or admin needs to make a change with content made by user.

Strange is that for automatic node title i can use node author tokens, but not for image field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this issue that explains why you cannot use node tokens in Views: https://www.drupal.org/node/1788414

> This is a limitation of Drupal core - it does not provide any node
>   context for token replacement aside from the global tokens that are
>   available. You will need a module like
>   http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths in order to use node tokens
>   in the file upload directory tokens.

The [File (Field) Paths module](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) provides this functionality:

> The File (Field) Paths module extends the default functionality of
>   Drupal's core File module, Image module and many other File upload
>   modules, by adding the ability to use entity based tokens in
>   destination paths and file names.
>
> In simple terms, File (Field) Paths allows you to automatically sort
>   and rename your uploaded files using token based replacement patterns
>   to maintain a nice clean filesystem.

That should allow you to use the `node:author` token.